# How to export a database from .sh to .sql?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I am working on Linux (Ubuntu), and I want to export the whole schema from **.sh** file to **.sql** in order to open it in MySQL Workbench - but how can I do it?

I have tried with `mysqldump` but it doesn't work, I wrote this command after opening **.sh database**, but I am not sure if it has some influence.

Command line in terminal:

`mysql> mysqldump -uuser -ppassword db > db.sql`

And it doesn't work - MySQL syntax error displays after that

Comment: Alternatively you could [reverse engineer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html) it directly out of MySQL WB.

Comment: mysqldump is not an SQL command. You should use mysqldump directly from Linux command prompt, not inside a MySQL command prompt.

Comment: Please add the MySQL error log

Comment: `.sh` files are shell scripts, not databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here .sh means a script file extension in which you will write your commands and .sql means a backup/dump file.

**Example**

Execute below command on linux prompt-

```
sudo vi backup_script.sh
```

It will open a blank file you can write your script here like -

```
cd /root/backup/
mysqldump -uroot -proot123 mydb > /root/backup/mydb.sql
```

Now save this file by Esc + : + wq

Note: backup folder should exist in root else you can create by below command-

```
mkdir /root/backup
```

Now you can execute backup_script.sh by below command-

```
sh backup_script.sh
```

It wil take your mydb database backup at /root/backup/ path.

Comment: "mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect" I used your commands and that error display after all

Comment: mysql database on same machine from where you are executing this script...and mysql is running right now.

Answer (score 1):

1.Install mysql-client which includes mysqldump

```
user@local:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.1
```

2. backup database

```
user@local:~$ mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

3. if you need you can import

```
user@local:~$ mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```